# Any way to "Admit people in Meet" using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

Currently i am using selenium to automate creating meeting in google meet and it works fine.
But i want to create a condition in which if a person requests to join the meet, it automatically accept it
but I am not having any idea how to do that, so pls if anyone can help me do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Therefore, we require a description of the problem, your own attempt at solving the problem, the errors you are getting and what the expected output is. If those boxes are ticked, some kind volunteer may help you out. Please refer to this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I hope you have a good time here!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium allows for easy Alert and Popup Window handling, [this resource](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html) may help you get started.

Comment: Be more specific what didn't work?Did you get an exception? You should try to be more specific so that the community can help you out.

Comment: sorry to be not so specific, I tested the alert handle popup in my router website and some othe websites which give you an alert message
The problem is "When the admit/deny entry pops up", alert dont detect anything, like it dont classify this as an alert.

Comment: for temporary ihave found a work aroud by adding an extension for enabling an autoadmit in meet. I saw the code of the extension and it was written in java script.
but i want to know that is there any way to make that happen in chrome.
anyway i am newbie so any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def admit():
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]').click()
        except:
            pass
```

This is the code that I just made and is working, I am feeling really dumb that I asked this simple question.